# Utilizando Tag "a" em formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html

É possível utilizar um input dentro da tag "a" e utilizar a mesma para submeter os dados do input em um formulário? Segue o código de exemplo.

@foreach ($links as $link)
        
            
        
    @endforeach

Answer (score -2):

O input vc usa para enviar os dados do formulario.

A tag "a" vc usa junto com href para referenciar um link, e quando clicar ser direcionado para pagina que voce colocar.

Ou seja, não tem sentido o que você está querendo fazer aí.
Tenta da uma olhada detalhada no que cada tag faz e elabora uma idéia melhor do que pretendes.

Comment: A ideia é a seguinte, além de abrir uma página, eu preciso que envie dados do site acessado. Tais como o dia e a hora em que foi acessado. E tem que ser de forma simultânea.